# Multiple same ajax requests are triggered on form submit in backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am developing an web app using backbone. In my backbone view i am using an event form submit. When the view is first time loaded the form submit is OK. But when i switch between router and then i submit my form it sends multiple same ajax request.

My view is following..

```
var View_AdvanceSearchArea = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    events: {
        'change #genderID': 'genderChange',
        'change #areaID': 'areaChage',
        'submit #advanceSearchForm': 'formSubmit'
    },
    genderChange: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getBodyHeightByGender',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '&genderID=' + $('#genderID').val(),
            success: function(res) {
                $('#bodyHeightID').html(res);
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getAgeByGender',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '&genderID=' + $('#genderID').val(),
            success: function(res) {
                $('#seventhDigitID').html(res);
            }
        });
    },
    areaChage: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'getSubAreaByArea',
            type: 'POST',
            data: '&areaID=' + $('#areaID').val(),
            success: function(res) {
                $('#subAreaID').html(res);
            }
        });
    },
    formSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = $('#advanceSearchForm').serializeArray();
        var vAdvanceSearchResult = new View_AdvanceSearchResult();
        vAdvanceSearchResult.render(formData);
    },
    render: function() {
        var $this = this;
        var mAdvanceSearchForm = new Model_AdvanceSearchForm();
        mAdvanceSearchForm.fetch({
            success: function(res) {
                var template = _.template($('#advance_search_area').html(), {res: res.attributes});
                $this.$el.html(template);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What is the problem?
Any Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call your view its events bind to the DOM element each time.
You have to undelegate the event from the DOM element when the view is initialized..

Try the following code in your view..

```
var View_AdvanceSearchArea = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page',
    initialize: function() {
        $(this.el).undelegate('#advanceSearchForm', 'submit');
        $(this.el).undelegate('#genderID', 'change');
        $(this.el).undelegate('#areaID', 'change');
    },
    //here is your rest of code
```

Hopefully, it works for you..

Answer (score 0):

1. Model_AdvanceSearchForm() is created in the render() method which can lead to the memory leak as you call render() in your router. It also can be a reason of unexpected behavior as HTML elements are detached from a view, but still exist in memory, so somehow take part in the even generation if they are bound to the model.
2. Also in formSubmit you create View_AdvanceSearchResult which can also lead to a memory leak or unexpected behavior.

For more information check out [this post](http://unspace.ca/blog/avoiding-memory-leaks-in-backbone/) or [Backbone.js CookBook](http://www.packtpub.com/backbonejs-mvc-rest-cookbook/book).

The solution is to create new objects you need only once in initialize() method instead of render() or formSubmit() and don't forget to dispose them when they are no longer required.